# Characterization of linear operators on $\Bbb{R}^2$ which are $\Bbb{C}$ linear.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

In my graduation, I got the intersting question in  linear algebra book *Hoffmann, Kunge*:

Give an example of a linear transformation $T$ on $\Bbb{R}^2$ which is not $\Bbb{C}$ linear, that is, $T$ is not $\Bbb{C}$ linear when $T$ is considered as a map from $\Bbb{C}$ to $\Bbb{C}$.

Then somehow I made this example $T(x,y)=(x+y,x+y)$ as an answer. But now I am curious about how one can define a map $T$ which is both $\mathbb{C}$ and $\Bbb{R}$ linear.

**Attempt**

If $T:\Bbb{R}^2\rightarrow\Bbb{R}^2$ is $\Bbb{C}$ linear, then $T:\Bbb{C}\rightarrow\Bbb{C}$ is $\Bbb{C}$ linear. Thus there is some $\alpha\in\Bbb{C}$ such that $T(z)=\alpha z$ for all $z\in\Bbb{C}$. Let $\alpha =a+ib$ and $z=x+iy$, then $T$ takes the form $T(x,y)=(ax-by,ay+bx)$ for all $(x,y)\in\Bbb{R}^2$.

So, Is this all the characterisation of such operator? Please correct me if there is any mistake or, give some improvement in the characterisation if possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's right. Another way to say it is that $T: \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}^2$ describes a $\Bbb{C}$-linear map $\Bbb{C} \to \Bbb{C}$ if and only if there exist $a,b \in \Bbb{R}$ such that the matrix representation of $T: \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}^2$ with respect to the "standard" basis $E :=\{e_1, e_2\}$ is
\begin{align}
[T]_E = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a & -b \\
b & a
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}

Comment: In other words, considering $\mathbb R^2$ as $\mathbb C$, you need to make sure that $T(i)=iT(1)$.